# how to use fit model to predict tomorrow's value?

Tags: python

I am learning time series forecast. Here is the code and it is working fine, the prediction is always comparing to test data. Now given the today's stock price from X, how can I predict tomorrow's stock Y( MSFT)price? This is the main goal of prediction.  Thanks

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
# Error Metrics
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
# Time series Models
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA
from matplotlib import pyplot
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
#Diable the warnings
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

stk_tickers = ['MSFT', 'IBM', 'GOOGL']
ccy_tickers = ['DEXJPUS', 'DEXUSUK']
idx_tickers = ['SP500', 'DJIA', 'VIXCLS']

stk_data = web.DataReader(stk_tickers, 'yahoo',start_date, end_date)
ccy_data = web.DataReader(ccy_tickers, 'fred')
idx_data = web.DataReader(idx_tickers, 'fred')

return_period = 5
Y = np.log(stk_data.loc[:, ('Adj Close', 'MSFT')]).diff(return_period).shift(-return_period)
Y.name = Y.name[-1]+'_pred'

X1 = np.log(stk_data.loc[:, ('Adj Close', ('GOOGL', 'IBM'))]).diff(return_period)
X1.columns = X1.columns.droplevel()
X2 = np.log(ccy_data).diff(return_period)
X3 = np.log(idx_data).diff(return_period)

X4 = pd.concat([np.log(stk_data.loc[:, ('Adj Close', 'MSFT')]).diff(i) for i in [return_period, return_period*3, return_period*6, return_period*12]], axis=1).dropna()
X4.columns = ['MSFT_DT', 'MSFT_3DT', 'MSFT_6DT', 'MSFT_12DT']

X = pd.concat([X1, X2, X3, X4], axis=1)

dataset = pd.concat([Y, X], axis=1).dropna().iloc[::return_period, :]
Y = dataset.loc[:, Y.name]
X = dataset.loc[:, X.columns]

validation_size = 0.2

#In case the data is not dependent on the time series, then train and test split randomly
# seed = 7
# X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=validation_size, random_state=seed)

#In case the data is not dependent on the time series, then train and test split should be done based on sequential sample
#This can be done by selecting an arbitrary split point in the ordered list of observations and creating two new datasets.
train_size = int(len(X) * (1-validation_size))
X_train, X_test = X[0:train_size], X[train_size:len(X)]
Y_train, Y_test = Y[0:train_size], Y[train_size:len(X)]

X_train_ARIMA=X_train.loc[:, ['GOOGL', 'IBM', 'DEXJPUS', 'SP500', 'DJIA', 'VIXCLS']]
X_test_ARIMA=X_test.loc[:, ['GOOGL', 'IBM', 'DEXJPUS', 'SP500', 'DJIA', 'VIXCLS']]
tr_len = len(X_train_ARIMA)
te_len = len(X_test_ARIMA)
to_len = len (X)

modelARIMA=ARIMA(endog=Y_train,exog=X_train_ARIMA,order=[2,0,1])
model_fit = modelARIMA.fit()

error_Training_ARIMA = mean_squared_error(Y_train, model_fit.fittedvalues)
predicted = model_fit.predict(start = tr_len -1 ,end = to_len -1, exog = X_test_ARIMA)[1:]
```

Comment: You just pass today's value into the `predict(...)`, the return value is what you want.

Comment: Thanks Sraw, Yes I just did it using the last value from x_test like this predicted_tuned_tomorrow = model_fit.predict(exog = X_test_ARIMA[-1:]) and it returns multiple values in the past. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi anyone here give me a hint? Thanks a lot